# Как сделать ленту как в инстаграм на PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, клиент-сервер

Нужно сделать на PyQt5 динамическое обновление содержимого окна, исходя от данных из сервера, например как лента инстаграм. Как это возможно осуществить? С сервера приходит список заказов и всё это надо красиво выдать на экране без использования таблицы, а как, например в на ленте в инстаграме.

Comment: `QListView`  наследование `QAbstractListModel` и переопределение его методов fetch... И, скорее всего, `QStyledItemDelegate`. Так что всё можно

Comment: Буду очень благодарен, если объясните поподробнее, Александр! Пожалуйста, не поленитесь, это очень важно сейчас для меня

Comment: Не поленюсь, но позже)

Comment: Спасибо, буду ждать

Comment: Ракшас, вы бы не ждали, а создали минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который показал пример получаемых данных и лучше  рассказали, что с этими данными вы дальше собираетесь делать. А также покажите как вы хотите видеть отображение этих данных в вашем окне.

Answer (score 0):

Как я уже отметил в комментарии, можно воспользоваться [QAbstractListModel](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtCore/QAbstractListModel.html) классом-моделью для списка элементов, в котором переопределить несколько ключевых методов:

```
class MyModel(QAbstractListModel):  

    # В этом методе принимается решение имеется ли возможность
    # подгрузить дополнительные данные
    def canFetchMore(self, parent):
        # Возвращаем смело True, если речь идет о котиках
        return True

        # либо, другой пример
        # допустим у нас в есть текущее число элементов в данной модели,
        # а БД говорит, что есть еще
        dbOrdersQty =  db.getOrdersQty()
        return ordersQty > self.currentOrdersQty
       
    # Если canFetchMore вернула True, то вызовится метод 
    # Получения информации доп.элементов
    def fetchMore(self, parent):
        # Тут мы загружаем дополнительные элементы списка (данных модели)
        
    # Текущее количество элементов данных (заказов)
    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return self.currentOrdersQty

    # Оставшиеся методы отвечают за передачу данных в отображение
    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return ''

        # Если таблица запрашивает данные для отображения
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.orders[index.row()]
        return ''
```

Скорее всего вам понадобится вывод данных не в просто ячейку списка,
а в какой хитрый фрейм, или виджет с кучей других виджетов на нем
Для этих целей надо наследовать класс [QStyledItemDelegate](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtWidgets/QStyledItemDelegate.html)
Допустим, у вас уже имеется некий кастомный виджет (MyCustomWidget), для ячейки списка, тогда его надо заполнить и отобразить в ячейке (и ячейку по размеру под него подогнать):

```
class MyDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):

        # Получаем данные заказа
        orderInfo = index.data(Qt.Display)

        customWidget = MyCustomWidget()
        customWidget.setTitle(orderInfo.title)  
        customWidget.setImage(orderInfo.image)
        ...

        # Отрисовываем наш виджет в ячейке списка отображения
        pixmap = QPixmap(customWidget.size())
        customWidget.render(pixmap)
        painter.drawPixmap(option.rect.topLeft(), pixmap)

        
    # Возвращаем желаемый размер ячейки в соответствии с размером виджета
    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        return MyCustomWidget().size()
```

После всего этого шабаша, устанавливаем объекты этих классов
в объект списка отображения:

```
self.ui.listView.setModel(MyModel())
self.ui.listView.setItemDelegate(MyDelegate())
```

Это фундамент для построения любого скроллируемого списка с любым внешним видом его элементов.